# Magento: echoing out certain element of array returned by model

Tags: php, arrays, model, magento-1.12

I am developing a module and I've now come to a point where I want to query a database table i added to the Magento database

I want to query the table looking for a specific value and it works.  it finds the correct row but what I want to do is use any of the values in the array

My table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `salesrule_coupon_facebook` (
  `entity_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `facebook_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf16 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`)
)
```

My resource model

```
<?php

class MyModule_Facebook_Model_Resource_Facebookcoupon extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('facebook/facebookcoupon', 'entity_id');
        $this->_storeId = (int)Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    }

    public function getData($code)
    {
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $select = $resource->getConnection('core_read')->select();
        $select
            ->from($this->getTable('facebook/facebookcoupon'))
            ->where('code = :code');

        $result = $resource->getConnection('core_read')->fetchAll($select, array('code' => $code));

        return $result;
    }
}
```

and the block that queries the database

```
<?php

class MyModule_Facebook_Block_Content extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    private $couponCode;

    public function checkFacebookId()
    {
        $model = Mage::getResourceModel('facebook/facebookcoupon')->getData('AXM-1547-4518-9884');

        var_dump($model);

    }
```

This is the output from the block class

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["entity_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["facebook_id"]=> string(8) "14547854" ["code"]=> string(18) "AXM-1547-4518-9884" } }
```

How do a use an element in that array so i can make comparisons etc if needed or even just print an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it myself like this

```
$model = Mage::getResourceModel('facebook/facebookcoupon')->queryData('AXM-1547-4518-9884');

foreach($model as $row) {
    echo $row['code'];
}
```